# Table width and `\marginpar`

Tags: tables, marginpar

I've a table in an article where I need `\marginpar`. To make the table more readable, I could eliminate the re-entry to the right, so that the table itself occupies all the horizontal space, including the one otherwise used for `\marginpar`. Here the relevant code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[right=4.5cm,heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.1in}
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{\oldmarginpar
{\raggedright\footnotesize\emph{#1}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
& {\em Capacità argomentativa} & {\em Capacità comunicativa} & {\em Esposizione} \\
\midrule
{\em Prologo}
  & Mette in luce la significanza, la rilevanza, l'attualità del tema
  & Precisa definizione dei termini del tema
  & Accattivante, coinvolgente, stimolante \\
\midrule
{\em 1° argomentazione}
  & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
  & Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente
  & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa  \\
\midrule
{\em Dialogo socratico} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\em Capacità di fare domande} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\em Capacità di dare risposte} \\
\midrule
                        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fecondo, non pretestuoso, incalzante, provocatorio} & Pronto, reattivo, rispettoso \\
\midrule
{\em 2° argomentazione}
  & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
  & Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente
  & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa  \\
\midrule
{\em Replica} & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
{\em Difesa} & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
{\em Epilogo} & Rende conto che la propria posizione è preferibile, fa la differenza & Sintetico, conciso & Icastico, coinvolgente, d'impatto anche oratorio \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{tabular with resizebox}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I didn't realize if I can use `\newgeometry`of `geometry`package, or if there is a better trick. Thank you

**2nd attempt**

Now I'm using `tabularX`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[right=4.5cm,heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}l> 
{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X> 
{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
& {\em Capacità argomentativa} & {\em Capacità comunicativa} & {\em 
Esposizione} \\
\midrule
{\em Prologo} & Mette in luce la significanza, rilevanza, attualità del tema
& Precisa definizione dei termini del tema & Accattivante, coinvolgente, 
stimolante \\
\midrule
{\em 1° argomentazione} & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
& Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa \\
\midrule
{\em Dialogo socratico} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\em Capacità di fare domande} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\em Capacità di dare risposte} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fecondo, non pretestuoso, incalzante, provocatorio} & Pronto, reattivo, rispettoso \\
\midrule
{\em 2° argomentazione} & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
& Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa \\
\midrule
{\em Dialogo socratico} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\em Capacità di fare domande} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\em Capacità di dare risposte} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fecondo, non pretestuoso, incalzante, provocatorio} & Pronto, reattivo, rispettoso \\
\midrule
{\em Replica} & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
{\em Difesa} & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
{\em Epilogo} & Rende conto che la propria posizione è preferibile, fa la differenza & Sintetico, conciso & Icastico, coinvolgente, d'impatto anche oratorio \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{tabularX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Problems (I mean bad settings): for I've only text in this table, it 
breaks through the right margin of body text in the case of two lines (`\em` lines), despite the presence of `\textwidth`.

In any case, this new table is wide as body of text, and doesn't occupy even the space of `\marginpar` (if needed)

Comment: Why not use `tabularx`' `X` type columns in order to allow for linebreaks in table cells and a table that is as wide as the available textwidth? This way you can also get rid of the `resizebox` command that leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in something like the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[right=4.5cm,heightrounded,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{calc}


%\setmainfont{EBGaramond}
%\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
%\PolyglossiaSetup{italian}{indentfirst=false}
%\frenchspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}{>{\em}l> 
{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X> 
{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\toprule
&  Capacità argomentativa & {\em Capacità comunicativa} & {\em 
Esposizione} \\
\midrule
 Prologo & Mette in luce la significanza, rilevanza, attualità del tema
& Precisa definizione dei termini del tema & Accattivante, coinvolgente, 
stimolante \\
\midrule
 1° argomentazione & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
& Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa \\
\midrule
 Dialogo socratico & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\em Capacità di fare domande} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\em Capacità di dare risposte} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}{Fecondo, non pretestuoso, incalzante, provocatorio} & Pronto, reattivo, rispettoso \\
\midrule
 2° argomentazione & Ben costruita logicamente, fondata, variamente supportata
& Pertinente e perspicua, completa, esauriente & Sicura, originale, ingegnosa \\
\midrule
 Dialogo socratico & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\em Capacità di fare domande} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\em Capacità di dare risposte} \\
& \multicolumn{2}{>{\hsize=2\hsize\centering\arraybackslash}X}{Fecondo, non pretestuoso, incalzante, provocatorio} & Pronto, reattivo, rispettoso \\
\midrule
 Replica & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
 Difesa & Ritorsiva, confutatoria, demolitoria & Puntuale, pacata, circostanziata, mirata & \\
\midrule
 Epilogo & Rende conto che la propria posizione è preferibile, fa la differenza & Sintetico, conciso & Icastico, coinvolgente, d'impatto anche oratorio \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\caption{tabularX}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: yes! Interesting the code `\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep` :) Thank you